# Adding a Link as a child of a Router with ReactDOM.render yields "You should not use <Link> outside a <Router>"

Tags: reactjs, react-router, leaflet, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I am looking for a way to use `ReactDOM.render` to create a `Link` within a react router. The setup more or less looks like this:

```
const router = (
  <div>
    <Router>
      <Route path="/map" component={Map}/>
    </Router>
  </div>
);
```

The relevant parts of `Map.jsx` look like this:

```
const MapPopup = () => {
  return (
    <Link to={`/map/add`} />
  )
}

class Map extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.map = L.map('map')

    //...stuff...

    this.map.on('contextmenu', event => {
      popup
        .setLatLng(event.latlng)
        .addTo(this.map)
        .setContent(
          ReactDOM.render(
            MapPopup(),
            document.querySelector('.leaflet-popup-content')
          )[0]
        )
        .openOn(this.map)
    })
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div id="map" />
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}
```

I am basically trying to add a `Link` to the map popup provided by leaflet (I can't use react-leaflet for this project). If I however return the MapPopup directly in the render function it works (obviously not in the popup but the Link does work this way).

```
<React.Fragment>
    <div id="map" />
    <MapPopup />
</React.Fragment>
```

Does anyone have an idea how I can tackle this rather unusual problem?

I am using `"react-router-dom": "4.3.1"`.

Comment: Not sure what you are doing inside `Link` but if you use a `props render` it does not exist. Here are the available [props](https://knowbody.github.io/react-router-docs/api/Link.html) you can use with react-router's `Link`

Comment: @kboul I believe the `props` are passed down from the `Link` to the parent `div` of the `Button`, i.e. `to`

Comment: I stripped out unnecessary parts now, hopefully making it a little more clearer.

Comment: Also added a codepen https://codepen.io/TimMcCauley/pen/xNLzZm

Comment: Rendering jsx inside `componentDidMount` is something unusual in React. Usually inside this lifecycle hook you only change the state or perform http requests. You should reconsider the way for what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the expected error since `<Link>` component expects ancestor component to be of  router type (`<BrowserRouter>`, `<MemoryRouter>`, `<Router>` ... ), refer [this thread](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/6140) for a more details.

For your scenario to circumvent this limitation [`ReactDOM.createPortal`](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html) could be utilized instead of `ReactDOM.render`:

```
<Route
    path="/popup"
    render={() => (
              <Popup>
                <div>
                  Some content goes here
                  <Link to="/map"> Back to map</Link>
                </div>
             </Popup>
          )}
/>
```

where

```
class Popup extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return ReactDOM.createPortal(
      this.props.children,
      document.querySelector("#link-render-div")
    );
  }
}
```

and

[Here is a demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-7gfvbf) for your reference

Comment: Thank you very much Vadim, works perfectly well with the portal.